# RelativeLayout and ListView inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to make an scrollable profile for my client for social network.

Here's my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_profile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="440dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_avatar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#0277BD"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_user_profile_avatar"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_friends_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                        <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_friends_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/friends"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                        <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_friends" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_followers_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                        <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_followers_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/followers"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                        <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_followers" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_groups_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                        <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_groups_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/groups"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                        <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_groups" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_photos_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                        <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_photos_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/photos"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                        <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_photos" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_videos_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                        <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_videos_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/videos"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                        <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_videos" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_audios_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                        <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_audios_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/audios"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                        <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_audios" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="34sp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/age_city"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:id="@+id/online_status"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fragment_user_profile_avatar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="35dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/age_city"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/online_status"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandable_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:transcriptMode="normal"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_profile"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And when I run my application, I can scroll my `ListView`, but user_profile layout just stay on its place. But I want to make it scrollable too. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

You're guys amazing! Big thanks for your help, now its working as should!

Comment: Don't put your ListView inside ScrollView. Take it out and then try.

Comment: @GokhanArik , ok, but how? i trying but then scrollview with relativelayout just fill the screen

Comment: ListView in Scrollview is not recommended. Have you tried to change the outmost `RelativeLayout` to `Linearlayout`?

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung, yes i tried, but it didnt make anything. just the same

Comment: Are you trying to have everything above the listview (i.e. relativeLayout1) scroll off screen as you go down the list? In that case, simply put that layout in another xml file, inflate it, and set it as the header of the listview. If you need a code example, let me know.

Comment: @TheRedBaron, i think your method should work, and if not hard for you, example of code would be good :)
Or, if u have hangouts, we can go there

Comment: just posted an answer with the code to get you going. hope that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**user_profile.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/user_profile"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="440dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_avatar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#0277BD"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_user_profile_avatar"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_friends_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                    <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_friends_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/friends"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                    <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_friends" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_followers_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                    <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_followers_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/followers"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                    <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_followers" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_groups_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                    <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_groups_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/groups"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                    <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_groups" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_photos_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                    <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_photos_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/photos"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                    <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_photos" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_videos_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                    <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_videos_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/videos"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                    <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_videos" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/header_user_profile_audios_container"  android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="33.0" style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">

                    <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_audios_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip" android:text="@string/audios"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                    <TextView android:textSize="26.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_audios" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/age_city"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:id="@+id/online_status"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fragment_user_profile_avatar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/age_city"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/online_status"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**list_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_profile"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" />
```

**YourActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

    // inflate header to add to list view header
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);
    listView.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_profile, listView, false));

...add list adapter/other setup
```

Comment: now another problem. listview automaticly scrolls to the down of list on application run. how to make it stay at the top(header)

Comment: try adding android:transcriptMode="disabled" instead of android:transcriptMode="normal" in the listview's xml.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to get rid of the ScrollView entirely and place the 'user_profile' RelativeLayout in a separate layout file, in order to inflate it as a header to your ExpandableListView. Like this:

```
ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_profile, listView, false);
listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all never put one scrollable container/widget inside another scrollable container widget - it will create problem (trust me, I tried it :) )

As far as I understand the problem you want to have scrollable list with user profile data at top of that?

I would do it that way

in adapter override

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return MY_VIEW_TYPE_COUNTER //for example 2;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
       return USER_PROFILE_TYPE_CONSTANT;
    else
       return NORMAL_LIST_ELEMENT_CONSTANT;
}
```

and after that in getView method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if(type == USER_PROFILE_TYPE_CONSTANT)
        /*inflate and set correct user profile view*/
    else
       /* inflate and set "normal" list item*/
    return convertView
}
```

Hope I understood the problem correctly :) If not please clarify

Comment: Thanks for your response, but user profile data should scroll with listview, so when i scroll up, profile data scrolling up too

Comment: then for me it sounds like the solution proposed by @TheRedBaron is the answer - put your user profile in other XML file, inflate in programmatically in activity/fragment with list, and add it as a headerview - it will simply stay at the top of the list no matter how you scroll :)

Comment: thats the problem. it shouldnt stay at the top, it should scroll off the screen with listview content

Comment: if you follow my code, it will not stay at the top. it will scroll with the rest of the list. :)